# How to check if a variable holds any value in if condition?

Tags: java

I was working on a problem, and I wanted to know how we can check if a variable holds any value inside the if condition in Java. Like in JavaScript, if we simply do like

Javascript code

```
let amount;
let discount;
if(amount){
    discount=10;
}
```

I can simply check here if amount holds a value or not in JavaScript.

This is the code I need help in:

case:  if I want to check if a variable holds a value in it?

```java
class Shop {
    private double amount;
    private int discount;

    public int getDiscount(){
        if(amount){  // err: cannot convert double to bool
           this.discount=10;
        }
        else{
          this.discount=0;
        }
        return this.discount;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Shop s1= new Shop s2;
       System.out.println("Discount="+ s1.getDiscount());
    }
```

Comment: A primitive class field always has a value. If it is not explicitly initialized, it is implicitly initialized with `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have `undefined` and `null` as Javascript has. Java has only `null` value.

In Java primitive variables like `double` when used as fields in some class, they are initialized to their default value (double uses the default `0.0`) if you don't provide any initial value.

But if you use the relative wrapped object like `Double` as class field it will not be initialized in default value (`0.0`) but `null`.

So you can use the wrapped object `Double` and check if it is `null`, since this will happen when no value is assigned to that field.

```
   class Shop {
    private Double amount;
    private int discount;
    
    public int getDiscount(){
        if(amount == null){ 
           this.discount=10;
        }
```

Comment: Arguably, fields of reference types *do* get initialized to their default value, but the default value for references is `null`.

Comment: @Hulk isn't the `But if you use the relative wrapped object like Double as class field it will not be initialized in default value (0.0) but null.` the same?

Comment: Yes, it is. This comment was really just nitpicking the wording.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a strongly typed programming language because every variable must be declared with a data type. A variable cannot start off life without knowing the range of values it can hold, and once it is declared, the data type of the variable cannot change. From [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/strongly-typed-2034295#:%7E:text=Java%20is%20a%20strongly%20typed,of%20the%20variable%20cannot%20change.)

This does not apply to javascript, that is why it can have the thruthy/falsey checks. In OOP languages you usually make null checks for objects (or look up NullObjectPattern) or in your case a default value check. Check if amount is the default double value.

Comment: Default value check is not always a good idea, you may confuse the variable never being set with a variable explicitly being set with the default value. We don't know what the OP wants to do with that discount rate but you may have a 0 amount because it has never been set or because it's the result of a positive and a negative flow, and we don't know in that case what the discount should be.

Comment: Agreed. My answer was targeting the error and a quick fix on how to avoid it in this particular scenario. In order to improve the logic, further work needs to be done and what you explained should be taken into consideration.

Comment: what is the alternative? can you tell

Comment: @AnuragSundriyal either you declare amount as Double (not double) and you perform a null check, or you declare a field boolean amountSet and set it to true the first time the amount value is set.